# Spring boot + MySql в докере

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker-compose, liquibase

Я только начинаю изучать докер и все с ним связанное, поэтому возникла проблема.
У меня есть свой сервис на spring boot который должен коннектиться к mysql. На хосте все пректрасно работает. Пытаюсь перенести все это в docker-compose, но почему то там, он не видит бд.

Вот мой докерфайл сервиса:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./hotel.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD sleep 30 && java -jar app.jar
```

вот проперти сервиса:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/senla_traineeship?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=testtest
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/db.changelog.master.xml
spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/senla_traineeship?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.liquibase.user=root
spring.liquibase.password=testtest
```

Так выглядит мой docker-compose.xml

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testtest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - 3306
 
  hotel:
    container_name: hotel
    build: ./hotel
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_SERVER: mysql:3306
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
```

А вот так выглядит ошибка, которую мне выдает мой сервис:
[image: код моей ошибки, как я понимаю проблема в liquibase]

Если имеет значение, у меня win 8. Что я делаю не так? вроде бы все по мануалам.

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких дней исследований, у меня получилось решить данную проблему.
Докерфайл не изменился. Проперти сервиса пришлось изменить. Теперь они выглядят так:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/senla_traineeship?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=testtest
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/db.changelog.master.xml
spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/senla_traineeship?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.liquibase.user=root
spring.liquibase.password=testtest
```

Докер compose теперь выглядит так:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: senla_traineeship
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testtest
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
hotel:
    container_name: hotel
    build: ./hotel
    expose: 
      - "8080"
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mysql:3306
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
```

Как я понимаю, проблема была в том, что сервис обращался к бд через локалхост, а надо было обращаться через имя хоста контейнера с бд(могу ошибаться). Поэтому мной были явно указаны имена для хоста.